# How to model grouped and ordered data with multinomial logistic regression with R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multinomial-logit

## Background information

Suppose we have a dataset for a competition in 2016 here.

```
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | Round | X1   | X2   | Rank |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 1     | .586 | .329 | 1    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 1     | .111 | .171 | 2    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | ...   | ...  | ...  | ...  |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 1     | .625 | .663 | 8    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 2     | .412 | .312 | 1    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 2     | .250 | .341 | 2    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | ...   | ...  | ...  | ...  |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 2     | .063 | .008 | 10   |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | 3     | .817 | .520 | 1    |
    +-------+------+------+------+
    | ...   | ...  | ...  | ...  |
    +-------+------+------+------+
```

Each season has many rounds and each round may have different number of contestants (e.g. Round 1 has 8 and round 2 has 10 as shown above). The contestants have to compete with each other in order to win the game. For example, contestant $i$, who gets rank '1', will be the champion while $j$, who gets rank '2', will be the first runner-up, etc.

What I am interested in (or the ultimate goal) is finding **the probability of 2 selected contestants in a certain round being the top two in correct order**.

So, I am going to model it with the following equation, which is a mixture of 2 multinomial logit models.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{P}(i,j,I) & = \mathrm{Pr}\left(V_i>V_j>V_k,k\neq i,j\right)\\
& =\frac{e^{\theta_i}}{\sum_{p=1}^I{e^{\theta_p}}}\cdot\frac{e^{c\theta_j}}{\sum_{q=1,q\neq i}^I{e^{c\theta_q}}}
\end{align}
$$
, where
$V_i=\theta_i + \epsilon_i$ is the utility of contestant $i$,
$ \theta_i = \beta_0+\beta_1X_{1,i}+\beta_2X_{2,i} $,
$ X_{s,i} $ is the $s$-th predictor for winner $i$,
$I$ is the number of contestants in a round, and
$c$ is a already determined constant multiplier between 0 and 1.

The likelihood function and the log-likelihood can thus be obtained as below,
$$
\begin{align}
L(\beta)&=\prod_{r=1}^R{\mathrm{P}(i,j,I_r)}=\prod_{r=1}^R{\left(\frac{e^{\theta_{i,r}}}{\sum_{p=1}^{I_r}{e^{\theta_{p,r}}}}\cdot\frac{e^{c\theta_{j,r}}}{\sum_{q=1,q\neq i}^{I_r}{e^{c\theta_{q,r}}}}\right)} \\
\log L(\beta)&= \sum_{r=1}^R{\left(\theta_{i,r}+c\theta_{j,r}-\log{\left(\sum_{p=1}^{I_r}{e^{\theta_{p,r}}}\cdot\sum_{q=1,q\neq i}^{I_r}{e^{c\theta_{q,r}}}\right)}\right)}\\
&= \sum_{r=1}^R{\left(\theta_{i,r}+c\theta_{j,r}-\log{\left(\sum_{p=1}^{I_r}{\sum_{q=1,q\neq i}^{I_r}{e^{\theta_{p,r}+ c\theta_{q,r}}}}\right)}\right)}
\end{align}
$$
, where
$\theta_{i,r} = \beta_0+\beta_1X_{1,i,r}+\beta_2X_{2,i,r}$,
$X_{s,i,r} $ is the $s$-th predictor for winner $i$ in $r$-th round,
$I_r$ is the number of contestants in $r$-th round, and
$R$ is the total number of rounds in a season.

## Obstacles

- Not sure how to model the probability **by round** instead of by contestant in R
- Using ordered logit seems to be more convenient but not sure how to transform the mixture to the desired
- Maximum likelihood estimates give me 2 double sums in a big sum which is computationally expensive even if I don't use any loops in R so I give up using my own program to find the MLEs
- I have also used SPSS built-in ordinal regression to model the probability but the results are not desirable and the constant multiplier cannot be included

## Main questions

So, my main questions are:

1. Is it possible to model the required probability with the `multinom` function in `nnet` package in R?
2. Is it more convenient to use ordered logit to model the probability?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To all whom may be concerned: while this asks explicitly about R, to me this sounds like a general modelling question and should be considered on-topic in here.